# Kohana получить категорию по id товара

Tags: orm, kohana

Делаю вывод случайных товаров в kohana. Генерацию случайных товаров сделал, но как узнать категорию каждого товара, возникает проблема.

```
$products = ORM::factory('product')->limit(3)->order_by(DB::expr('RAND()'))->find_all();
```

Вывод товаров:

```
<div class="left">
    <h3>Случайные товары</h3>
    <?php if(count($random_items) > 0): ?>
    <?php foreach($random_items as $product): ?>
        <div class="random_item">
            <?php if(count($product->images->find_all()) > 0): ?>
                <?=html::anchor("catalog/view/id_категории/$product->id",
                    html::image('public/uploads/' . $product->main_img->name, array('width' => '75')))?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?=html::anchor("catalog/view/id_категории/$product->id",
                    html::image('public/img/no-image.jpg', array('width' => '75')))?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <p><?=html::anchor("catalog/view/id_категории/$product->id", "$product->title")?></p>
            <p><span><?=$product->price; ?> грн.</span></p>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Нет товаров</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну к примеру: 
1.Есть категория Все для футбола (в родительская)->Мячи(дочерняя)
2.Есть категория Мячи для игр (родительская)->Футбольные

Я добавляю товар в категорию мячи и в категорию футбольные.
На многих интернет магазинах я видел такую реализацию. Конечно чуть я согласен, в принципе как то с одной стороны глупо так делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пф... если у товара, я надеюсь, есть `category_id`, то опишите связь в ORM для categories - `$_has_many`, а для товара - `$_belongs_to`. И выводите хоть все товары в категории, хоть обратно - категорию товара в виде `$item->category->name`.

update 1.

ну, тогда для вывода категорий товара используйте:

```
foreach($item->categories->find_all() as $category)
{
// some code
}
```

update 2.
В ORM есть метод, считающий количество связанных элементов и вместо

```
<?php if(count($product->images->find_all()) > 0): ?>
```

используйте

```
<?php if($product->images->count_all()): ?>
```

Comment: В категории идет связь:
protected $_has_many = array(
        'products' => array(
            'model'   => 'product',
            'through' => 'products_categories',
        ),
    );

в продукте
protected $_has_many = array(
        'categories' => array(
            'model' => 'category',
            'foreign_key' => 'product_id',
            'through' => 'products_categories',
            'far_key' => 'category_id',
        ),

Comment: у вас один товар может лежать в нескольких категориях?

Comment: да, может лежать в нескольких категориях.

Comment: мсье знает толк... хм, а зачем, если не секрет?

Comment: не  совсем понял ?

Comment: зачем 1 товар "лежит" в нескольких категориях?

Comment: Спасибо, все работает как Вы и написали.

Comment: а зачем товар-то в двух категориях? Приведите пример, пожалуйста, где это целесообразно